# Is there an alternate way of printing the following design in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print

```
 |
 |/ 
\|
 |/
```

My code is printing

```
\|/
\|/
\|/
\|/
\|/
\|/
 ^
```

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


    //int i = 0;
    for (int i=1;i <= Height;i++ ) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            stringBuilder.append("|/");break;
        }


        else  {
            stringBuilder.append("\\");}


    }
    //stringBuilder.append("/");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that code can make that pattern. After the first even number (`2`) you `break` out of the loop.

Comment: But you're close. You should remove that `break`. And initialize the `StringBuilder` with `" |"`. Add newlines to each line. And change the `"|/"` to `" |/"` and the `"\\"` to `"\\|"`.